# ConstraintLayout takes extra space around it when it is included inside Toolbar (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) widget

Tags: toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-constraintlayout

Today I'm facing an unexpected problem. When trying to use ConstraintLayout inside a Toolbar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) widget , it's takeing extra space around it for nothing.And when I use it (ConstraintLayout  with same xml code) inside anther layout like LeanearLayout it works fine (It does not take any space unexpectedly around it).

my_inside_toolbar.xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:background="#f90511"
>     tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
>     tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">
>
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/button4"
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
>         android:background="#000"
>         android:text="Button"
>         android:textColor="#fff"
>         app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
>         app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button5"
>         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/button5"
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
>         android:background="#0b8653"
>         android:text="Button"
>         android:textColor="#fff"
>         app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
>         app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button6"
>         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button4" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/button6"
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
>         android:background="#000"
>         android:text="Button"
>         android:textColor="#fff"
>         app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
>         app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button5" />
> </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
> ```

design view for the above xml below:

[image: ConstraintLayout desing mode picture]

When I include this xml inside my_toolbar.xml problems arises.

Here is 
my_toolbar.xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:background="#f5e903">
>
>     <include
>         android:id="@+id/la"
>         layout="@layout/my_inside_toolbar.xml" />
>
> </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
> ```

Design view for the above xml below:

[image]

Note: Here Yellow color is the background for toolbar widget. And the extra yellow background shows the unexpected space.

Now my questions:
Is it possible to use ConstraintLayout inside a Toolbar so that it can cover the full body of its parent (toolbar)?
If possible then how to solve the problems which I am facing now?

Any answer and suggestion will be praised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the part of new *Material Design Specification* introduced in version **24.0.0** of *Design Support library.*
It is possible to remove the extra space by adding the following property to Toolbar widget.

```
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
```

As mention by @kocus in comments adding `app:contentInsetStart="0dp"` solved his problems, I originally misinterpreted the problem.

Comment: but Sir this property does not work for me. what should i do before adding this property?

Comment: Adding `app:contentInsetStart="0dp"` on the Toolbar element solves the issue.